# move single MKCircle among multiple circles on map in objective c

Tags: objective-c

I have to move or resize one MKCircle among multiple circles on map. I am able to do if I have only single circle on map. I am getting circle radius and its latitude, longitude through web services. Is there any Id property of circle or how can I create multiple objects of circle? For single circle, I am writing below code:

```
 if(circle != nil)
        {
            [_mapView removeOverlay: circle];
            circle = nil;
        }
    if (circle == nil) {
         circle=[MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coord radius:radius];
        [self.mapView addOverlay:circle];
    }
```

Please help me what should I do code if I have more than one circle?